# Vim delete starting from character to end of line

Tags: vim

I'm trying to come up with something that will delete all text to end of line from a given character onwards.

E.g. in the example below I want to keep only the IP address:

```
192.168.2.121/32 -m comment --comment "blah blah bye bye"  -j DROP
10.1.3.207 -m comment --comment "much longer comment with all kinds of stuff" -j DROP
172.16.1.0/24 -m comment --comment "Drop this range" -j DROP
```

The pattern to remove from is `-m`, i.e., reading from left, the first "-" encountered. From that "-" to end-of-line should be deleted on every line in the file.

I'm stumped on this one, guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 28):

A global command would be a good fit

```
:g/-/norm nD
```

Explanation

```
:g         : Start a Global Command (:h :g for extra help on global commands)
/-         : Search for -
/norm nD   : Execute nD in Normal Mode where 
               n - jumps to the match
               D - delete to the end of the line
```

Comment: Is there a global command to delete from the beginning of the line to a given character?

Comment: @anishjp - yes, try `%norm 0dt<character>`

Comment: Thank you for that. If I have to also delete the given character?

Comment: @anishjp - `%norm 0df<character>`

Answer (score 24):

There's a simple method to do that under the normal mode:

1. `/-m` to let the cursor move to the first occurrence "-m" in the file.
2. Press `d$` to delete characters from the cursor to the end of the line.
3. Press `n` to find another "-m".
4. Press `.` to redo step 2.

Comment: "Press d$ to delete characters from the cursor to the end of the line." this is what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Isn't this as simple as:

```
:%s/-m.*//
```

?

Or I didn't understand the problem right?

Comment: In this case, `%s/ .*//` would do as well.

Comment: @LucHermitte sure it is gonna work for OP's example data. however his requirement was from `-m`. So I would follow what OP said, instead of the example. Otherwise it could be as easy as `:%norm! WD`

Comment: No, it's not simple. It's anything but simple.

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
:%norm f D
```

"On each line, move the cursor to the first space and cut everything from the cursor to the end of the line."

```
:help range
:help :normal
:help f
:help D
```

Answer (score 1):

I would register a macro, for example:

1. Put the cursor on the first line, at position `0`
2. `ql` start registering a macro on the letter `l`
3. `t-D+`
4. `q` end the macro
5. Launch the macro as many times as you want eg: `3@l` to launch it three times

Explanation of `t-D+`:

- `t-` goes in front of the next occurence of `-`
- `D` delete till end
- `+`, jumps to the next line at the beginning of the string so that we can chain macros (`l` should work too on vim as you deleted till the end)

As @Nobe4 stated you can also register the macro on one line (eg `qlt-Dq`) and then repeat on a visual selection: `VG:normal!@l`.

Comment: If you have a macro that operate line-wise, you can repeat it over a range of line with `:'<,'>normal! @q`, which may be useful also :)

Comment: '<,'> is the visual selection no? Btw it doesn't work to me.

Comment: strange, if you try your macro without the `j0` at the end ? And to achieve this, you can select a set of line with `v`, then pressing `:` should give you `:'<,'>`

Comment: My bad, I used the wrong letter (you typed `q` I used `l` here ;)). Thanks for the tip, I'll improve my answer. Why doesn't this work with `%` as a buffer instead of the visual selection?

Comment: two comments: 1) `d$` could be `D` 2) `j0` could be `+`

Answer (score 0):

Select your text with visual mode and then use:

```
:'<,'>s/\([^- ]*\).*/\1/
```

Decomposition:

```
:'<,'>s/     " start a substitution on current selected lines
\([^- ]*\)   " capture a groupe of everything except a space and a -
.*/          " match the rest of the line
\1/          " replace by only the matched group
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the cursor to the beginning of the line need to be removed.
2. press key `d` twice to remove the line.

ref: https://alvinalexander.com/linux/vi-vim-delete-line-commands-to-end/

Answer (score 0):

```
shift-d
```

is another way to remove characters from current position to the end of the line.
Acts the same way as `d$` does.
Literally, "from current position to the end of line, inclusive".